# How to Dock a PyQt window in Maya

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4, maya

I am working with PyQt in Autodesk Maya 2013 and was curious how to set up your window to dock. Using maya.cmds its quite easy to do and I feel like it should be easy to do here but I am not quite sure how. If anyone can help me out I would be quite appreciative, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.jason-parks.com/artoftech/?p=439

Jason gives here a nice exemple commented line by line.